# hook_form_alter() exposed filter form item #weight

Tags: views, forms, hooks

I'm trying to insert a form element with `hook_form_alter()`, and then rearrange the form elements so that the new form item appears at a particular point amongst the existing exposed filters.

I've tried adding `#weight` of `0` to all existing items and then `#weight` of `-1` to the new element, just to see if I can have any influence on the form item order at all, however I don't seem to be able to affect it.

**EDIT:** In addition I'm getting kinda weird behaviour regarding the container of the Form element. I'm adding my form element as a new array element at the root of `$form`, however it is be rendered inside the element `<div class="views-exposed-widget views-submit-button">` rather than getting it's own container, which seems like either a bug or I really am doing something wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at comments #3, #7 and #9  in http://drupal.org/node/893392

#3 (dereine):

> The problem is that there is some theming on exposed form. You would have to override it, sadly.

#7 (manatwo):

> Yes, all of it is handled in views-exposed-form.tpl.php, which you can override in your theme to print out your fields manually. IIRC, the extra fields are gonna be in the $button variable in that template, so you might want to do some preprocessing in template.php

#9 (PadreHomer):

> I was able to alter the order without overriding the template. I am using Views 3, but I think this will work in Views 2 as well.
>
> Alter the order of the filters in $form['#info'] in your form_alter and this should alter the order the widgets print out in the template without having to do any custom templating.

Comment: Ahh this is a little unfortunate, I really enjoy nice clean hooks and overrides, shame something as respected as Views kinda messes with this! Thanks for the info though :)

Comment: Ahh having looked into it deeper now, comment #9 is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @DanH: I also tried with #9, but no success. its not at all changing its weight. FYI: I have enabled better exposed filter in views and I have secondary filter as well.

Answer (score 2):

A small update on this (as I have just updated http://drupal.org/node/893392 too), if someone faces similar problem in the future, as I just did myself, trying to place my new exposed form item in-between "widgets" generated automatically by the view - the solution is to turn that new form item into a widget, and then re-order widget array in the `$form['#info']`.

In my case I was adding new `community` form item into Views exposed form, and then wanted it to be displayed as a second element in the form, right after `filter-title` generated by the view:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-mw-group-list-page-1') {
    // Add new form item.
    $form['community'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Community'),
      '#options' => $options_array,
      '#default_value' => $default_value,
    );
    // Create widget from new form item and place it as a second element.
    $new_form_info = array(
      'filter-title' => $form['#info']['filter-title'],
      'filter-community' => array('value' => 'community'),
    );
    $form['#info'] = array_merge($new_form_info, array_diff_assoc($form['#info'], $new_form_info));
  }
}
```

Obviously the code responsible for re-ordering `$form['#info']` will look different depending on where the new form item should be displayed.